# There's a big gap at the beginning of my fragment and I can't remove it

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm currently working on an app.
While working on one of my fragments I realized there's a big gap at the top that I can't remove.

I tried adding this:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

to my layout but it doesn't work.

I also tried adding this to my RecyclerView:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Post the XML of the view you are inflating for each ViewPager element please.

Comment: @I am a Student I approved your edit. May I give a small editing tip? Code and XML work best when put in `code markdown`.